# I am trying to create a report where the rows are fixed and the columns are variable

Tags: jasper-reports

is there a way in *JasperReports* to create a report where the rows are fixed, e.g., 2 rows, and the columns are variable, e.g., 5 columns or 10 columns at run time?

Answer (score 1):

Say you are using a `table` component to display you data in jasper report. And you require your columns to show up dynamically.

In that case `printWhenExpression` helps you achieve your task. Its a property just like any other property of a component in jasper report.

The best part about `printWhenExpression` is that you can set conditions in it and apply to a component to display it.

For e.g. A `text field` is to be displayed when value of other text field is `1`. You can simply put:

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{FIELD_TWO}.intValue() == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
```

`You need to apply the same logic and same property to table colums` to achieve such behavior. For more on it visit [this](http://helicaltech.com/blogs/dynamically-hiding-the-columns-in-table-component-in-ireport/) link.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Darshan...thanks for the suggestion...you have given me another perspective and i will be able to use it for the purpose you have mentioned... however, my case is that i only have two columns and instead of showing the rows/records horizontally, i want to show it vertically, i.e., as columns. is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but the dig is you'll have to manage your data and jasper report design accordingly.